# how does the gradle dependencies work, i can not find any function relate with it in the gradle source code

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

how does the gradle dependencies work,  i can not find any function relate with it  in the gradle source code.
please help me ,  I googled  this but found nothing...

```
dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gradle dependencies work from build.gradle(Module:app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       ....
    }

    dependencies {
     ...........
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: '..'

repositories {
    .....
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your pkg name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

//**Here you can add your dependencies**

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
........
```

}